# Add list elements to dictionary values

Tags: python

```
myList=[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
myDict={"1":0,"2":0,"3":0,"4":0,"5":0,"6":0,"7":0,"8":0,"9":0,"10":0}
```

#new dictionary should look like this:

```
{"1":11,"2":12,"3":13,"4":14,"5":15,"6":16,"7":17,"8":18,"9":19,"10":20}
```

#the problem is how to change dict values with list elements

Comment: `dict(zip(mydict, mylist))`

Comment: don't use "list" and "dict" as variable names,

Comment: was feeling bad while writing the question :(

Comment: Do you need the old dictionary at all? `dict((str(key), val) for key, val in enumerate(list, 1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `dict(zip())` or just generate it

```
a = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
b = {"1": 0, "2": 0, "3": 0, "4": 0, "5": 0, "6": 0, "7": 0, "8": 0, "9": 0, "10": 0}

result = dict(zip(b, a))
print(result)
# {'1': 11, '2': 12, '3': 13, '4': 14, '5': 15, '6': 16, '7': 17, '8': 18, '9': 19, '10': 20}

result = {str(i): i + 10 for i in range(1, 11)}
print(result)
```